# Archiving Domains Objects with Abstract Domains

Tags: grails, grails-orm

let's say I have an existing Domain Book within an Grails 2.1.5 project. And so far I was always deleting Books from this table. But now I would like to not physically delete Books, but archive them. So that I don't have to change anything in the code where I do Book.get/findXX/executeQuery/... or even Author.books -> so that I only find Books that are not archived.

So I think that might work very nice (since Grails > 2.x) with usage of Extending Domain Classes.

e.g.

```
class ArchivableBook {
    // some properties
    static mappings = {table 'book'}
}

class Book extends ArchivableBook {
    // ...
}

class HistoricalBook extends ArchivableBook {
    // ...
}
```

(Maybe it's even enough to just let HistoricalBook extend Book)

I know that on DB level there will be a column 'class' in Book that will identify if it's a Book or a HistoricalBook.

So here is my question:
What is the best way to archive a Book now? Somehow it seems to me that i would just need to set the class column to the new value... But so far I did not figure out how to do that in an easy way. Is it possible to cast Book to HistoricalBook and than save it? Or would I have to delete the Book and create an HistoricalBook with the same Id?

Answer (score 3):

So I would approach this differently

Add an "archived" property onto your existing class.

```
class Book {
    ...
    Boolean archived
    ...
}
```

Then instead of delete simply set this to true.

Then use the [hibernate filters plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) to filter out the archived books.

```
class Book {
    ...
    Boolean archived
    ...
    static hibernateFilters = {
        notArchivedFilter(condition:'archived=0', default:true)
    }
}
```

This will work in all cases except when a query is not done from a standard request (Quartz job as example) or if done via `.get()`. `.get()` can be changed to `.findById()`.

Comment: Cool thing. Thanks for the answer. Did not think of that ;) Would this work for executeQuery() and criterias? And would this work if I there is class Author { hasMany[books:Book]} . So that if I reference Author.books I only find the ones that match the default filter?
As I pointed out in another comment, usage of Book is allover the application, and I would like to touch as less as possible. Of cause I don't want to teach every developer to use .findById instead of .get for Book. But if it's only this, it might be an option. Or I could overwrite .get()
Anyway.. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You'll have to look at the plugin documentation to see the specifics as for how it applies to the way you are using Book, but I can tell you it works with criteria queries and HQL.

Answer (score 0):

The 'class' column that you are referring to is called the discriminator column, and I don't believe you can change it, at least not easily.  I think you will find that going down that path will cause you more headaches than benefits.

However, you could create an abstract class in src/groovy and have two domain classes inherit from it.  Then, you will end up with two tables (Book & HistoricalBook) with common fields.  In your `Book.delete` service/controller function, you could create a `HistoricalBook` and drop the `Book`.

** EDIT **

in **src/groovy/(package name)/ArchivableBook.groovy**

```
abstract class ArchivableBook {

    String name
    //other properties

    static constraints = {
      ...
    }

}
```

in **grails-app/domain/(package name)/Book.groovy**

```
class Book extends ArchivableBook {
    // ...
}
```

in **grails-app/domain/(package name)/HistoricalBook.groovy**

```
class HistoricalBook extends ArchivableBook {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately that would not solve my main issue -> not showing Books that are archived.
Book.get
Book.findXX
Book.executeQuery
Author.books
...
is all over the application. 
I would like to use this construct to 'delete' Books. And only be able to find HistoricalBooks where I need to. e.g. tracking log files where Book.id is in.

I know I could overwrite getters and stuff, but that was my first shot and turned out to be too risky and not maintainable.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that this was in production already.  I modified my answer to reflect an alternative approach.  In addition to the response above, you could also look at [multiple datasources](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources) to archive data. e.g. Copy to 'archive' datasource and delete from 'production'.

Comment: Hey, thanks again ;) 
Yep I was considering this also. The Book table in my case is not so huge, that's why I like the idea of having the discriminator and all objects in one table.
I was hoping that there is a way to do something like: 

ArchivableBook book = Book.get(1)
book = book as HistoricalBook
book.save()

or something similar that just updates the discriminator value.

Fallback would be something like:
Book book = Book.get(1)
Historical hbook = new HistoricalBook(book.properties)
hbook.id = book.id
book.delete()
hbook.save()

And that's what I would need to archive with your approach

Comment: So in the end, if I decide to use your approach, archiving would need to be done in the same way. At least I can still split the table if it gets too big ;)

Comment: Right, the act of 'archiving' would be creating an instance of a `HistoricalBook` and deleting a `Book`.  However, given @James Kleeh's answer, I would probably go in that direction. I was unaware of the hibernate filters plugin.  Sounds like you could just run an update: `Book.archived = true` instead of making any `Book.delete()` call.